# Get a list of multiple values in a lookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, lookup

In my Excel workbook, I have a sheet `testers` with 2 columns depicting a list of testers and a third boolean column as email sent flag.

- A tester email
- B tester name - irrelevant for current issue
- C email has been sent or not - irrelevant for current issue

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| email | name | emailed |
| `jack@company.com` | Jack | 0 |
| `mack@company.com` | Mack | 0 |
| `iris@company.com` | Iris B | 0 |

A second sheet `allocations` has information on which widget has been assigned to which testers:

- A widget ID
- B email of tester 1 assigned to the widget (data validation from column A of `testers` sheet)
- E email of tester 2 assigned to the widget (data validation from column A of `testers` sheet)
- columns C-D and F-J are not relevant for the current issue.

As shown in the example below, widget 990235 has been assigned to Jack and Mack.

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| widget_id | email1 | email1thanked | rating1 | email2 | email2thanked | rating2 | actionsent | difference | average |
| 990235 | `jack@company.com` | 0 |  | `mack@company.com` | 0 |  | 0 |  |  |
| 990236 | `mack@company.com` | 0 |  | `jack@company.com` | 0 |  | 0 |  |  |
| 990231 | `jack@company.com` | 0 |  | `iris@company.com` | 0 |  | 0 |  |  |
| 990197 | `iris@company.com` | 0 |  | `mack@company.com` | 0 |  | 0 |  |  |
| 990003 | `mack@company.com` | 0 |  | `iris@company.com` | 0 |  | 0 |  |  |

I am trying (and failing) to figure out how to get a list of all `widget_id`s allocated to any particular tester.

e.g. for `jack@company.com` I should get the list "990235, 990236, 990231"

I understand that `VLOOKUP` is not sufficient as it would find the first match and stop. Besides, my understanding (I may be wrong) is that `VLOOKUP` matches the first column and the lookup needs to be to the right of it, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this formula in cell `D2` of the *testers* sheet:

```
=MAP(
    A2:A4,
    LAMBDA(φ, TEXTJOIN(", ", , IF(allocations!B2:E6 = φ, allocations!A2:A6, "")))
)
```

Adjust the ranges as required.

Edit: assuming the entries in column A of the *allocations* sheet are numeric, a version which will work up to the last column A entry in each sheet:

```
=LET(
    κ,MATCH(7^89,allocations!A:A),
    MAP(
        DROP(TOCOL(A:A,1),1),
        LAMBDA(φ,
            TEXTJOIN(
                ",",,
                IF(allocations!B2:INDEX(allocations!E:E,κ)=φ,
                   allocations!A2:INDEX(allocations!A:A,κ),"")
            )
        )   
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked, and I have accepted. However, could you please elaborate what the different parts are and basically how it works?

Comment: P.S. Also, if I don't know upfront how many rows I will have in either `testers` or `allocations` sheets, how do I go about adjusting it?

Comment: @OC2PS Added a version which detects the last rows in column A of each sheet.